# Is using typedef as a way to facilitate alternate class names a misuse?

Tags: c++, typedef

In my C++ library, throughout many modules, I use `typedef` like this:

```
class ClassName {
//...
}

typedef ClassName AlternateClassName;
```

I do this to simply enable myself and potentially others to allow my classes to be called by names other than their official ones--nothing more than a synonym. Is this an OK use of `typedef`?

Comment: One pitfall of this is that you cannot use the `AlternateClassName` as a forward declaration (well, you still have to INCLUDE the file, which defeats the purpose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typedef` is fine here but its modern replacement `using` is better. `using` uses the more usual left-to-right syntax and it can also be templated

```
template <typename T>
using vec_size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;

vec_size_type<int> sz;
```

The alternative with `typedef` is clumsy:

```
template <typename T>
struct vec_size_type{
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type type;
};

vec_size_type<int>::type sz;
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that `typedef`'s syntax is intended to be the same as the declaration of a variable. `int x;`, variable. `typedef int x;` `x` is an alias to `int`. It also has a very C flavour, so `void(*fp)();`, function pointer. `typedef void(*fp)();`, `fp` is an alias to a type that provides a function pointer.

Comment: @user4581301 Good point of view. I think I should find another failure case for `typedef` for this answer.

Comment: You've nailed it here. You can `typdef` anything, but the difficulty of doing it can get... Yuck. Function pointer could make a good failure case. I've seen some really ugly nightmares.

Answer (score 5):

It is a valid use case. Another case for this is often to use for instantiated templates.

```cpp
typedef std::vector<int> DynamicInts;
```

If you are using C++11 then I would instead suggest the [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) keyword.

```cpp
using DynamicInts = std::vector<int>;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an OK use of typedef?

IMHO, yes.

I have worked with more than one team which used the idea for "compression" of class names. I heard no complaints about it.

```
class ClumsyButAccuratelyDescriptiveName_t {
//...
}

typedef ClumsyButAccuratelyDescriptiveName_t CAD_t;
```

Comment: The products I have worked on were embedded systems for telecom transport.

Comment: Do note that names ending with `_t ` are reserved.

Comment: @Ayxan I think that is only for POSIX.

Comment: Thanks.  ... I had not seen '_t'  reserved anywhere, but found it today for 'C and posix'.    See: 'https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html' "Some additional classes of identifier names are reserved for future extensions to the C language or the POSIX.1 environment. "   I have not yet found this reserved for c++, but I do use the occasional POSIX function in my c++ code.  Hmmm.

Comment: ALSO, on the production teams where I used the '_t' suffix (for compression and other issues), all such classes were part of a unique namespace. Thus, CAD_t   was defined in (for example) namespace HIL (where HIL was a local jargon (or acronym) meaning hardware-interface-layer), becoming HIL::ClumsyButAccuratelyDescriptiveName_t.  I think this would prevent any conflict with Posix definitions.  But I suppose macros (such as "CAD_t") would still be a challenge.