# Access type through another type in the same namespace

Tags: c++

I have two structs `A` and `B` that live in the same namespace.  For architectural and compatibility reasons I want to have `A` accessible through `B`.

I tried the following which is not working:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    static void print()
    {
        std::cout << "hello SO!" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B
{
    typedef A A;  // error here
};

int main()
{
    B::A::print();
    return 0;
}
```

Apparently the typedef to the same name is not working.  With `g++` I get the following error:

```
foo.cpp:13:15: error: declaration of ‘typedef struct A B::A’ [-fpermissive]
     typedef A A;
               ^
foo.cpp:3:8: error: changes meaning of ‘A’ from ‘struct A’ [-fpermissive]
 struct A
```

It would work if I give it an other name (e.g. `typedef A A2`) but I want it to keep the same name.

Interestingly, it is actually working when I compile with clang but I would need code that also builds with gcc.

Is there some way to achieve this (i.e. being able to do `B::A::print()`)?

I am currently using C++11 but going to a newer version might be possible if it is necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use `typedef ::A A` or `using A = ::A`

https://godbolt.org/z/VVKk3V

Comment: @Ayxan `struct A` seems to be in the global namespace in the OP's example code.

Comment: @Ayxan The global namespace is a namespace.

Comment: @Ayxan No more than `foo::A` is specific to the `foo` namespace and won't work for any other namespace like `bar`.  I don't see any reason to suppose that the OP won't realize you need to change the namespace appropriately.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica you're right. I'll delete my previous comments then

Comment: Is there some technical difference between `typedef` and `using` that I should be aware of?

Comment: @luator I consider `using The_New_Name = An_Existing_Type` more readable as it is similar to an assignment, e.g. `int the_new_var = 8765`

Comment: @luator `using` can be templated, `typedef` cannot be directly templated. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58514017/10147399)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace NS {
struct A {
  static void print() { std::cout << "hello SO!" << std::endl; }
};

struct B {
  using A = NS::A;
};
}  // namespace NS

int main() {
  NS::B::A::print();
  return 0;
}
```

[Compiles fine.](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7qXvM)

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it is more concise and was a little bit faster but +1 for giving an example with a namespace.